# how do i get the IP of my VM?

Tags: ip, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I did a partial clone of my VM. It is red hat 64 bit.

How do I get the external IP of the new instance of the VM?

Comment: go to whatismyip.com

Comment: Logging in and running `ip address show` isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really provided much information about your environment - your public facing IP should be the same as it was before and that is whatever IP is assigned to your gateway.

You can easily check this with [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com).

Comment: thanks! i guess i am looking for internal IP. i have two VM's on a physical machine and i want them to communicatge

Answer (score 1):

Most linux/unix flavors will respond to

```
/sbin/ifconfig -a
```

Most Windows flavors will respond to

```
ipconfig /all
```

Comment: thanks so much! i need 2 vm's on the same physical machine to speak to each other